# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT - Runs fine in the simulator

Tags: ios, sigabrt

I have read about this error, but what I find is in relation to XIBs and connectors.

I have looked, but I can't find any issues with my connectors... However I am still getting this error when I get to this line of code:

`NSMutableString pageData = [pacUtils requestErrorHistory:pac_ipAddr:pacPort];`

This is calling a function in the class "pacUtils".  I can step through the method "requestErrorHistory" and it doesn't have any issues until it returns back to this line of code.

Also, it runs fine in the simulator...

This is the only error in my log, but it has was there last release too (that runs fine) because I cannot actually find any reference to this png file. Even if I open the XIB in a text editor.

"2017-11-15 10:51:38.002688-0500 pachistory[5466:2789765] Could not load the "icon_pac-list-1.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.automationdirect.pachistory""

I am running under Xcode 9.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

"requestErrorHistory":

```
-(NSMutableString *) requestErrorHistory:(char *)ipToConn:(NSString *)port {
// Make sure we have a good network...
if ( ![self checkNetwork] ) {
    return nil;
}


char eventBuffer[175], critBuffer[175], noncritBuffer[175];
struct sockaddr_in PhoneAddr, BorgAddr;

if (allHist == nil) {
    allHist = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @""];
}

//Event history
eventBuffer[0] = 0x00;
... finish defining message...

//Critical errors
critBuffer[0] = 0x00;
... finish defining message...

// Non-critical errors
noncritBuffer[0] = 0x00;
... finish defining message...

/* create a socket for sending to the pac address */
if ((errHistSock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0) { 
    NSLog(@"ERROR: requestErrorHistory - socket() failed"); 
    return nil; 
}  

memset(&PhoneAddr, 0, sizeof(PhoneAddr)); 
NSString *phoneIP = [self getIPAddress];

const char *charIp = [phoneIP UTF8String];
PhoneAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
PhoneAddr.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr(charIp);

if (bind(errHistSock, (struct sockaddr *) &PhoneAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0) { 
    NSLog(@"ERROR HIST: bind not successful"); 
    return nil; 
} 

/* construct a pac address structure - erase everything in the structure first*/ 
    memset(&BorgAddr, 0, sizeof(BorgAddr)); 

BorgAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
BorgAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipToConn);
BorgAddr.sin_port = htons([pacPort intValue]);

/* send string to pac address */ 
if ((sendto(errHistSock, eventBuffer, sizeof(eventBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &BorgAddr, sizeof(BorgAddr))) != sizeof(eventBuffer)) { 
    NSLog(@"ERROR EVENT: requestErrorHistory - sendto() sent incorrect number of bytes"); 
    return nil; 
} 

[self buildHTMLHeader:@"Event History"];

[self retrieveErrorHistory:ipToConn:port:errHistSock:YES]; // First process the event history

/* send string to pac address */ 
if ((sendto(errHistSock, critBuffer, sizeof(critBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &BorgAddr, sizeof(BorgAddr))) != sizeof(critBuffer)) { 
    NSLog(@"ERROR NON-CRIT: requestErrorHistory - sendto() sent incorrect number of bytes"); 
    return nil; 
} 

[self buildHTMLHeader:@"Error History - Critical"];

[self retrieveErrorHistory:ipToConn:port:errHistSock:NO]; // First process the critical error history

[self buildHTMLHeader:@"Error History - Non-Critical"]; 

/* send string to multicast address */ 
if ((sendto(errHistSock, noncritBuffer, sizeof(noncritBuffer), 0,     (struct sockaddr *) &BorgAddr, sizeof(BorgAddr))) != sizeof(noncritBuffer))       { 
    NSLog(@"ERROR CRIT: requestErrorHistory - sendto() sent incorrect number of bytes"); 
    return nil; 
} 

[self retrieveErrorHistory:ipToConn:port:errHistSock:NO]; // First process the non-critical error history
[allHist appendString: @"</div>"];

close(errHistSock);
return allHist;
}
```

"retrieveErrorHistory":

```
-(NSMutableString *)retrieveErrorHistory:(char *)ipToConn:(NSString *)port:(int)errHistSock:(BOOL)isEventHistory {

    struct sockaddr_in broadcastAddr;
    unsigned int broadcastPort = [pacPort intValue];
    char recvString[1057];
    socklen_t broadcastAddrLen = sizeof(broadcastAddr);
    int bytes_received;

    recvString[1056] = '\0'; // Put a null terminator on the end of the string...

    memset(&broadcastAddr, 0, sizeof(broadcastAddr));
    broadcastAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    broadcastAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipToConn);
    broadcastAddr.sin_port = htons(broadcastPort);

    retrievedHistory = NO; // reset flag...
    [self startHistoryTimeoutMonitor];

    if ((bytes_received = recvfrom(errHistSock, recvString, 1057, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&broadcastAddr, &broadcastAddrLen)) < 0) {
        NSLog(@"retrieveErrorHistory: recFrom Failed");
        [self closeHistorySocket];
        return nil;
    }

    retrievedHistory = YES; // got the history...

    BOOL wasHistory = NO;
    int rowBegin = 18;
    int COL1_BEGIN = 0;
    int COL1_LENGTH = 7;
    int COL2_BEGIN = 8;
    int COL2_LENGTH = 8;
    int COL3_BEGIN = 17;

    // The timestamp on the event history is not the same length...
    if (isEventHistory) {
        COL2_LENGTH = 5;
        COL3_BEGIN = 14;
    }

    for (int totalRows = 20; totalRows > 0; totalRows--) {
        NSString *row = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", &recvString[rowBegin]];
        NSString *trimmedRow = [row stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];     
        if ([trimmedRow length] >= 15) { // 15 character is the size of the date/time... it should be at least that long...
            [allHist appendString: @"<tr style=\"vertical-align: top;\">"];
            [allHist appendString: @"<td style=\"border-left: Solid 1px #000000; border-right: Solid 1px #000000;font-size:34px;"];
            [allHist appendString: @"border-bottom: Solid 1px #000000; width: 15%; padding-right: 10px;"];
            [allHist appendString: @"padding-left: 10px; vertical-align: center;\"><p style=\"\""];
            [allHist appendString: @"align=\"left\">"];

            [allHist appendString: [trimmedRow substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (COL1_BEGIN, COL1_LENGTH)]]; 
            [allHist appendString: @"</p></td>"];
            [allHist appendString: @"<td style=\"border-left: Solid 1px #000000; border-right: Solid 1px #000000;font-size:34px;"];
            [allHist appendString: @"border-bottom: Solid 1px #000000; width: 15%; padding-right: 10px;"];
            [allHist appendString: @"padding-left: 10px; vertical-align: center;\"><p style=\"\""];
            [allHist appendString: @"align=\"left\">"];

            [allHist appendString: [trimmedRow substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (COL2_BEGIN, COL2_LENGTH)]]; 
            [allHist appendString: @"</p></td>"];
            [allHist appendString: @"<td style=\"border-left: Solid 1px #000000; border-right: Solid 1px #000000;font-size:34px;"];
            [allHist appendString: @"border-bottom: Solid 1px #000000; width: 40%; padding-right: 10px;"];
            [allHist appendString: @"padding-left: 10px; vertical-align: center;\"><p style=\"\""];
            [allHist appendString: @"align=\"left\">"];

            [allHist appendString: [trimmedRow substringFromIndex: COL3_BEGIN]];  
            [allHist appendString: @"</p></td></tr>"];
            wasHistory = YES;
            rowBegin = rowBegin + 52; // 52 is the spacing between each row in the message
        }
        else {
            break;
        }

    [row release];
    //[trimmedRow release]; //Crashes when I release it....??
    }

    if (!wasHistory) {
        [allHist appendString: @"<tr style=\"vertical-align: top;\">"];
        [allHist appendString: @"<td colspan=\"3\" style=\"border-left: Solid 1px #000000; border-right: Solid 1px #000000;font-size:34px;"];
        [allHist appendString: @"border-bottom: Solid 1px #000000; width: 15%; padding-right: 10px;"];
        [allHist appendString: @"padding-left: 10px; vertical-align: center;\"><p style=\"\""];
        [allHist appendString: @"align=\"left\">"];
        [allHist appendString: @"No History to Display\n"];
        [allHist appendString: @"</p></td></tr>"];
    }

    [allHist appendString: @"</table>"];
    [allHist appendString: @"<p>&#160;</p>"];
    return allHist;
}
```

Comment: `[pacUtils requestErrorHistory:pac_ipAddr:pacPort]` That's a really bad way to declare methods in Objective-C. Parameter should be "introduced", something like `-(NSMutableString *)requestErrorHistoryAtIPAddress:(NSString *)ipAddress andPort:(NSString *)port` Show us the code of `requestErrorHistory::`

Comment: posting... it now

Comment: Update your question with that code.